# Single Sign using the SSO Waffle icw Identity DotNet Framework 2.0

Tags: asp.net, single-sign-on, iccube

In icCube config.xml it is possible to use the SSO Waffle. This only works for SSO for windows users logging into the Windows environment.

Is it possible to make the SSO Waffle work with a web module that authenticates users with the ASP.NET Identity 2.0 framework?

Comment: I have not been able to get this to work and I have created a workaround with the help of icCube. This works perfectly.